# How do I get apache to forward web service requests to tomcat?

Tags: apache, tomcat

I know websphere does it, so there must be something that lets apache figure out what needs to go to the app server and what it can handle itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options. You can use [mod_jk](http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/webserver_howto/apache.html) or [mod_proxy_ajp](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy_ajp.html) to forward your requests. I generally use mod_proxy_ajp because it is shipped with Apache 2.2 and doesn't require me to install anything extra.